# Переход с eclipse на intellij idea

Tags: android, eclipse

Таки решился. Вкусности перевешивают привычку сразу - поработал несколько дней и возвращаться уже не хочу, но столкнулся с тем что в отличие от `eclipse` не подтягивается автоматом `support library` и не могу найти где указать минимальную версию платформы. Я понимаю, что наверняка прекрасно подтягивает и настраивается, а все дело в кривых руках)) 
Также буду благодарен за любые советы, позволяющие в полной мере использовать все возможности этого прекрасного продукта 
Спасибо

Comment: Не понял вопрос. В чём у вас проблема? Берёте android-support-v*.jar и добавляете в зависимости проекта.

Comment: просто привычка ) в eclipse это делалось автоматически по мере необходимости, добавить руками можно - ничего критичного, но все же смысл использования различных ide  в облегчение работы и хотелось бы этот процесс автоматизировать

Comment: Ну, если уж совсем лень, то в IntelliJ IDEA есть Platform Settings -> Global Libraries. Создайте там зависимость, после чего сможете добавлять её в нужные проекты одним кликом.